# add a background image to progressive web app splash screen?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest):

> In Chrome 47 and later, a splash screen is displayed for a web
>   application launched from a home screen. This splashscreen is
>   auto-generated using properties in the web app manifest, specifically:
>   `name`, `background_color`, and the icon in the `icons array` that is
>   closest to 128dpi for the device.

I'm wondering if its possible to use a full screen background image instead of the generated background?

Comment: Since adding background images to splash screens can not be done, I recommend reading the [W3C documentation](https://w3c.github.io/manifest/#purpose-member). It is much more detailed than [mozilla's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest) and there is a discussion in progress on development which you can find on [github](https://github.com/w3c/manifest/issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check the documentation about [Adding a Splash Screen for Installed Web Apps in Chrome 47](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/splashscreen).

> If you want to ensure that an icon will always be displayed consider that 48dp is the minimum image size we will display, which if you take the maximum density display currently supported (4x) then 48 * 4 = 192px. This is lucky because we need to 192px image for Add to Homescreen to work! Yay. Therefore, I would recommend always having 192px as the minimum sized icon and create 3 other versions at 256px, 384px and 512px. However, if you want to ensure that the user is not downloading too much data for the splash screen, especially on a low density device then you can go lower and Chrome will try to fetch the most appropriate image.

It stated that the maximum density display currently supported is 4x of 48dp.

You can file a [feature request](https://developers.google.com/web/feedback/) for this.

Comment: Thanks. I had seen this doc and it appears to specify that the "minimum" image size is 48dp, with "128dp [being] the ideal size". But it doesn't seem to specify a *maximum* size. Apologies if I am misinterpreting this. I suppose since it's not mentioned that it's not possible, but it would be better if it was explicit.

Comment: How is this an answer? The OP asked for a background-image on the splash screen, not icons. As I have read the docs extensively, it appears this can not be done. Using icons to fake a background most certainly is a hack. Since the implementation is in working draft, I would not suggest using hacks or workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option to background images on splash screens. (no hacks) It is not a simple or elegant solution, but then again, progressive web apps aren't either.

You could simply just let your splash screen load, then when your URL finally loads, you could use Javascript to fire an event that styles your own custom "mock" splash screen before the rest of your document loads. Although this might feel kind of "hacky" for the end-user, it is really just a workaround and does not affect how the manifest works in any way. If you go this route, I suggest using *media queries* to test for the `display-mode`. This way, your CSS will know when your application is in a certain mode and then you can style accordingly.

Your CSS `styles.css`:

```
/* the wrapper will be visible later after the document loads */
#wrapper { display:none; }

/*
Using a media query to test for the display-mode of your application
*/
@media all and (display-mode: fullscreen) {
   body {
      margin: 0;
      border: 5px solid black;
   }
}

#splash_screen {
   /* all your splash screen styles */
}
```

Make sure you declare the display mode in your manifest:

> "display": "standalone"

Your HTML;

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

<script type="text/javascript">

/* with setTimeout you have control over how long the
splash screen sticks because the document will load first. */
setTimeout( function() {
   var wrapper= document.getElementById("wrapper") ;
   var splash_screen = document.getElementById("splash_screen") ;
   document.body.removeChild(splash_screen) ;
   wrapper.style.display = "initial" ;
   } , 2000 ) ;

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="splash_screen"></div>

<div id="wrapper">
/* the rest of your content */
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

MDN documentation on [CSS display-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/display-mode).
MDN documentation on [manifest display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/display).

I was trying to find a way to use background images on splash screens myself, which is how I ended up here. In my pursuit, I came up with the mock splash screen idea. Be advised, I have not tested this code.

Comment: You will probably need to add a `z-index` property to the splash-screen and one to the wrapper as the wrapper will naturally have a higher z-index, since it is the last child of it's parent.